# How do I troubleshoot Web API projects?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, logging, api-gateway

I have tried this github repository - https://github.com/johnph/simple-transaction and sometimes it works (I can login), sometimes it doesn't (I can't login even with correct username and password). When I can't login, it only throws `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` or `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. This general message is not helpful to me to troubleshoot.

The project uses Application Insights for logging but I don't want have credit card to register for Azure account. I tried to put breakpoint in the web api projects (Identity.WebApi.Controllers,Authenticate method), but it doesn't reach the breakpoint also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally to test web api we use [Fidler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), these tools gives you the possibility to fully test your restfull service and vue the http status of the execution

here is an example of invalid authentication error in fidler :

[image]

when you double click on the request you can see further details

[image]